# Why isn't this foreign key reference working?

Tags: mysql

Please consider the following SQL.  I'm trying to create a table that references another.  The foreign key isn't being enforced and I don't know why.

```
--drop database test;
create database test;
use test;

create table person (
    id         int         auto_increment,
    name         varchar(30),
    primary key (id)
);

create table message (
    id         int         auto_increment,
    senderid    int,
    receiverid    int,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (senderid) references person(id),
    foreign key (receiverid) references person(id)
);
```

If I do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE message`, I get the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `senderid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `receiverid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `senderid` (`senderid`),
  KEY `receiverid` (`receiverid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note that the foreign keys senderid/receiverid are just themselves.  Without adding any rows into person:

```
mysql> insert into message (senderid, receiverid) values (1,2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from person;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from message;
+----+----------+------------+
| id | senderid | receiverid |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |        1 |          2 |
+----+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why isn't my foreign key working?

Comment: I think you need to use InnoDB to be able to use foreign keys: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: seems to be working on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/948cf) (*try to uncomment then build and it will generate the error.*)

Comment: @JohnWoo: sqlfiddle's default storage engine is InnoDB.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output above shows engine is `MyISAM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `MyISAM` but, as documented under [Foreign Key Differences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html):

> For storage engines other than `InnoDB`, MySQL Server parses the `FOREIGN KEY` syntax in `CREATE TABLE` statements, but does not use or store it.

Suggest you use `InnoDB` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked this.